# Converting a parametric survival model to a cash flow model. How do I account for aging in the population?

Tags: survival, censoring, nonparametric, hazard

I'm building a survival model for time to failure of widgets. Other members of the team want to convert the model to a cost flow model. The basic idea is that we can use the functional form of the survival function under the parametric approach (where we assume a logistic distribution) to estimate the cohort level survival curve. Then they can calculate that if 10% of the population has failed after 1000 days, we will incur $100,000 in replacement costs.

The estimation population is all widgets which have survived to 1000 days; that is the only criteria by which you are chosen as part of the population. We have the dates of all the failures, and all the widgets that have survived to the present day are considered censored.

However, when we do the prediction, we will be predicting time to event for any widget that is 1000+ days old. And this is the part I'm struggling to account for. If a widget has survived for 100 additional days, this information should be included in the model somehow, but I can't figure out what rigorous approach would be.

I thought I might be able to use the conditional hazard function, and exploit the relationship between the hazard and the survival function by taking the integral in a piecewise fashion. $S(t)$ is 1 for all days between 0 and 100 and then the $\exp(\int_{100}^th(t))$ thereafter, but that feels very hackerish and isn't getting me the results I expected (that might also be because the model is crap).

Comment: correct me if I am wrong: you population consists only of widgets that lasted for 1000+ days. Widgets that failed before then are not included, correct? *If a widget has survived for 100 additional days*, by this you mean the widget has survived for 1100 days, and you would like to construct a new survival curve for them. Or do you mean they enter the study at 1100 days?